# Trying to transfer Meteor component to a React app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I've had an app in Meteor JS, but now I'm trying to transfer React component from there to a plain React JS app. I'm having a problem with the part that initializes mongo db.

```
    import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
import numeral from 'numeral';

export const Players = new Mongo.Collection('players');

export const calculatePlayerPositions = (players) => {
  let rank = 1;

  return players.map((player, index) => {
    if (index !== 0 && players[index - 1].score > player.score) {
      rank++;
    }

    return {
      ...player,
      rank,
      position: numeral(rank).format('0o')
    };
  });
};
```

It just won't work. I already installed `npm install MongoDB` but the app still refuses to work. I think that MongoDB has a different syntax for a plain React app?

Here's my component to add players.
    ***mport React from 'react';

```
import {Players} from './../api/players';

export default class AddPlayer extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit(e) {
    let playerName = e.target.playerName.value;

    e.preventDefault();

    if (playerName) {
      e.target.playerName.value = '';
      Players.insert({
        name: playerName,
        score: 0
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="item">
        <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <input className="form__input" type="text" name="playerName" placeholder="Player name"/>
          <button className="button">Add Player</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: By "plain react" you mean what exactly? Where are you intending to get your data from to feed your components?

Comment: Michel, I'm adding players with another component. I just added it to my main post. I meant I'm using a React boilerplate from Facebook get started guide.

Comment: So it doesn't have Mongo DB integration. Is there a way to make react understand the same MongoDB syntax?

Comment: Not that I know of. You'd have to include much of Meteor to do that.